# C++ CMake error in VisualStudio - can't find CRABMEAT library

Tags: c++, cmake, package

I'm new to Visual Studio and have had very little experience with C++. I have a project that I'm trying to open in VS Community 2022. All I've done so far is open a folder that has a CMakeLists.txt file in it, so it is automatically running through things. It hits an error and stops:

CMake Error at Lconfig/packages.d/crabmeat.cmake-inc:7 (message):
Did not find CRABMEAT library.

In the crabmeat.cmake-inc file, it just looks for the package/library "crabmeat":

```
# vim: ft=cmake

find_package( crabmeat QUIET )
if ( CRABMEAT_FOUND)
    message( STATUS "found CRABMEAT library.  [lib=${CRABMEAT_LIBRARY},include=${CRABMEAT_INCLUDE_DIR}]")
else( CRABMEAT_FOUND)
    message( FATAL_ERROR "Did not find CRABMEAT library.")
endif( CRABMEAT_FOUND)
```

I have been searching online to find out what crabmeat is, with zero success. Then I found crabmeat mentioned in a compiler.h file:

```
/*!
 * @brief
 *    set our own macros for compilers
 *
 */

#ifndef  LDNDC_COMPILERS_H_
#define  LDNDC_COMPILERS_H_

/** compiler detection **/
#include  "crabmeat-compiler.h"

/* clang (llvm), note: have before gcc because clang also identifies as gcc.. */
#if  defined(CRABMEAT_COMPILER_CLANG)
#  define  LDNDC_COMPILER_CLANG
/* pgi */
#elif defined(CRABMEAT_COMPILER_PGI)
#  define  LDNDC_COMPILER_PGI

... etc etc
```

"crabmeat-compiler.h" doesn't appear to exist as a file.

Could someone please explain what crabmeat is and how I get it so I can move forward? I've also searched for it in the components of the VS Installer and nothing comes up, so I'm at a loss.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd imagine whoever you got this code from would be the best person to ask where to get the crabmeat library

Comment: Communicating with them has been difficult, hence the wider audience. I'm beginning to think it's something they developed in-house. I don't know why it wouldn't be included with the source code, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it's either developed in-house, or at least it's a local version. I was given a Subversion link to download it from their repository, in any case.